# adding sub gh-pages to a Project page

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a [project](https://github.com/Bondifrench/mithril-employee-directory) on github which has different folders, each represent a step in a tutorial and contain their own web page. The structure is the following

Rootfolder

- Iteration1
- Iteration2
- Iteration3

etc...

- Iteration7

I would like to deploy the content of each Iteration to their own gh-page/project page, what is the process to realise this.
Basically what I want to achieve is to have the following web-pages:

username.github.io/projectname/Iteration1

username.github.io/projectname/Iteration2

etc..

username.github.io/projectname/Iteration7

I know how to deploy a subfolder to github pages thanks to [this](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) but following this would mean that only one Iteration is deployed at username.github.io/projectname, which is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: Can you post the link to your repo?

Comment: Sure, added, it's a work in progress though.

Comment: and you want to get url http://bondifrench.github.io/ ?

Comment: For example, I've https://github.com/NaiveShark/soft url'ed to http://naiveshark.github.io/soft/

Comment: No, I would like `bondifrench.github.io/mithril-employee-directoree/iteration1`, and `bondifrench.github.io/mithril-employee-directoree/iteration2` etc.. one for each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a project repository `github.com/username/projectname` if you want to publish you have to put your code on a `gh-pages` branch.

I've cloned your repo, created a new gh-pages branch and pushed it to Github.

http://pygmeeweb.com/mithril-employee-directory/iteration1/

http://pygmeeweb.com/mithril-employee-directory/iteration2/

Comment: I was hoping for a variation of `git subtree push --prefix mithril-employee-directory/iteration1 origin gh-pages` (haven't tried that yet)

Comment: What worked in the end was, when inside the `mithril-employee-directory`, write the following command `git push -f origin master:gh-pages`, I didn't need to clone my repository

Answer (score 0):

You need the `mithril-employee-directoree` repo for your `bondifrench` user, and `gh-pages` branch in your repo. Put your `iterationN` folders to `gh-pages` branch, and you've got the `iterationN` folders on you host. Link it with `a href='iterationN\page'` in html.

[GH help](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages)